# Extract the rows in csv files in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a csv file without column name and have different sections located in a single csv, how to extract the study section in R and make it look tidy?

```r
# Read the CSV file in R 
data1 <- read.csv("data.csv", header = F)

Activities      
Date    Calories_Burned Value1  
Value2  Value3  Value4
1/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
2/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
3/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
        
Sleep       
Date    Calories_Burned Value1  
Value2  Value3  Value4
1/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
2/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
3/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e

Study       
Date    Calories_Burned Value1  
Value2  Value3  Value4
1/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
2/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
3/6/2021    a   b   
c   d   e
```

What I want to output:

```
Study       
Date    Calories_Burned Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
1/6/2021    a   b   c   d   e
2/6/2021    a   b   c   d   e
3/6/2021    a   b   c   d   e
```

Comment: just to clarify- what is the contents of `data.csv`? Is it everything in the first code block after `read.csv("data.csv", header = F)`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your file doesn't contain tabulation and only spaces and it doesn't contain truncated lines or missing columns/lines.

the idea is to select only the last section of your file from "Study" to the end of the file.
Then create a temporary table with the odd number lines and even number lines in order to bind them into the final file you want.

```
# Read the CSV file in R 
data1 <- read.csv("data.csv", header = F)

# Find the rows where "Study" section starts and ends
study_start_row <- which(data1[,1] == "Study")
study_end_row <- nrow(data1)

# Subset the data frame to include only the "Study" section
study_data <- data1[(study_start_row + 1):(study_end_row), ]

# trim whitespace
study_data <- trimws(study_data,whitespace = " ")

# Get every odd lines
tmp <- unlist(lapply(study_data[seq(1,length(study_data),2)],function(x) strsplit(x," ")))

# remove empty elements in vector
tmp <- tmp[nzchar(tmp)]
# Calculate the number of rows and column of the temporary table
num_rows <- length(study_data[seq(1,length(study_data),2)])
num_col <- length(tmp) / num_rows
#recreate the first columns
mat1 <- matrix(tmp, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_col, byrow = TRUE)

# Same thing with the even lines
tmp <- unlist(lapply(study_data[seq(2,length(study_data),2)],function(x) strsplit(x," ")))
tmp <- tmp[nzchar(tmp)]
num_rows <- length(study_data[seq(2,length(study_data),2)])
num_col <- length(tmp) / num_rows
mat2 <- matrix(tmp, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_col, byrow = TRUE)

# Recreate the dataframe
study <- as.data.frame(cbind(mat1,mat2))

# Use the first line for column names then remove the line
colnames(study) <- study[1,]
study <- study[-1,]
```